# 18.04 Server - can't install much of lamp suite through standard repos with apt

Tags: apt, server, 18.04, lamp, phpmyadmin

I'm deploying a small VPS, needing standard LAMP. The problem is, I can't install standard software through `apt`, like `phpmyadmin`, some php libs, nor even `mc`. Also can't find `xrdp`.

I've picked the x64 server live ISO.

Please help

Comment: Please add to your question the output of this command: `sudo apt install phpmyadmin mc xrdp`.

Comment: phpmyadmin, mc and xrdp are in the `universe` repository - did you enable it?

Comment: the output form @zwets req is`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package mc is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package phpmyadmin
E: Package 'mc' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package xrdp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package [`phpmyadmin`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=phpmyadmin&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all) is in Universe repository. You may have to enable this first:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install phpmyadmin mc xrdp
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I got it to work only after  applying "apt clean".

In particular:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
sudo apt install packyouneed
```